# Creating a Struct in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, struct

I want to create a struct like this in MySQL:

```
CREATE TYPE EMP_DATA(
    SSN Number(9),
    FirstName VARCHAR(20),
    LastName VARCHAR(20),
    Salary NUMBER(9,2)
);
```

But it keeps telling me that I have an SQL syntax. I cannot find on the web how to create user-defined types in MySQL. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: What do you mean? Am I disabled?

Comment: see here for how to accept an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: If you really need this kind of things you need to migrate to e.g. PostgreSQL or DB2

Comment: @juergend Hey! I'm sorry, I finally learned to accept questions. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MySQL does not support User-Defined Datatypes.

The available ones are [HERE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-types.html).

Answer (score 1):

User defined types are not supported in MySQL.